# Unable to write files with copy

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: Unable to write file (Error code: EISDIR)
```

I'm trying to copy all files and sub folders in a directory.

The below works when I omit ** but then none of my files are copied.

Any ideas how to fix the error?

```
copy: {
        main: {
            options: {
                expand: true
            },
            files: [
                { src: 'public/static/**', dest: '../../../public/packages/xyz/hello'}

            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `dest` is interpreted as a file, but is actually a directory, thus the error. Try postfixing it with a slash:

```
dest: '../../../public/packages/xyz/hello/'
```